# Text above image even though I want it below

Tags: graphics

Latex keeps putting the image below the text, even though the text is below the image in my source code. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Here is my source code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.25ex}
 ...
\section{Component II: Shifters}
    For this component, we used some sub-circuits, and we shall explain those first.

\subsection{Diagram \& Description}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.56]{ob.png}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What code did you use to create the picture in your question? You should also consider reading [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: @Werner I edited

Comment: you have not provided a test file that shows the issue, but the only function  of the `figure`  environment is to specify that its content can be taken out of the document flow and inserted elsewhere to help with page breaking (known as a float) so what you describe is the expected behaviour.

Comment: looking at your output screenshot, there is not room for the image below the haeading so your `h` option can not be used so it used the `t` option, placing it at the top of the next page. This would appear to be a good outcome.